# why does my range function not begin at the 'start' value?

Tags: python, range

there is a common HW problem to list all prime numbers using python, and using SO and other sites have found solutions to this using for loops similar to the below:

```
def count_primes(num):
primes = []
for y in range (2, num):
    for z in range(2, y):
        if y % z == 0:
            break
    else:
        primes.append(y)
return primes
```

When I  print the first instance of z,y i get below:

```
(2,3)
```

my question is then, why is the first instance of y = 3?

given that the range is (2,num) , wouldn't the instances of y run from 2 through num - 1?

obviously if the above were true, 2 would not be in the list, but I cannot wrap my ahead around why it starts with 3 to make this function work.

additionally, when I checked the values using print, y does indeed start a 2, but starts with 3 after the second for loop:

```
    def count_primes(num):
    primes = []
    for y in range (2, num):
        print(f'y = {y}')
        for z in range(2, y):
            print(f'y = {y}, z = {z}')
            #if y % z == 0:
                #break
        #else:
            #primes.append(y)
    #return primes

    count_primes(5)
```

this returns:

```
y = 2
y = 3
y = 3, z = 2
y = 4
y = 4, z = 2
y = 4, z = 3
```

I appreciate any clarity you can provide on this y value

*I believe it to be because range(2,2) essentially is not valid, so it loops again to y=3, but if anyone can confirm (or better yet) explain why this happened that would be great

Comment: Hint: try `list(range(2, 2))`. Hopefully that is all you need to answer the question for yourself.

Comment: `"I believe it to be because range(2,2) essentially is not valid"` it's not that it's "not valid", it's just empty because `range`'s `end` is exclusive

Answer (score 1):

Yes, when the start value equals the stop for a range, the iterator is empty - i.e. no iterations that time around.

Answer (score 1):

```
x = 1
y = 5
for i in range(x, y):
    print(i)
```

will give the output as:

```
1
2
3
4
```

Notice that `y=5` and `5` is not printed.

ie, the upper bound is equal to one less than the given

So, in this case: `range(2, 2)` and `range(2,3)` does not have any.